# from November to March

Tags: meaning, time

> a. From November to March, I caught a cold three times.
>
> b. From November till March I caught a cold three times.
>
> c. Between November and March, I caught a cold three times.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct and meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all correct and meaningful. They mean the same thing. Most people would not notice any difference at all. However the third one is the best.

When we say 'from ... to ... ' we are usually describing the time frame of a continuous or regular action.

> From November to March it rained every day.
>   From November to March I was happy.

But in this case you are describing separate events that happened over a period of time. They aren't continuous or regular events and their separateness is emphasized by their being counted (tree times). The third example is a better construction for describing this situation.

If you wanted to use either of the first two you could say

> From November to March I caught a cold every six or seven weeks.
>   From November to March I kept catching colds.
>   From November to March I caught colds a lot.

These describes your catching a colds as a regular or continuous event that continued to happen over a period of time instead of separate events, so it fits the sentence construction better.